# glm::quat why the order of x,y,z,w components are mixed

Tags: c++, quaternions, glm-math

I just started working with quaternions and noticed that the order of glm::quat elements are mixed. This is what I mean by this. If I declare a glm::quat like this

```
glm::quat quat = glm::quat(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

and then print the x,y,z,w like this

```
std::cout << quat.x << " " << quat.y << " " << quat.z << " " << quat.w;
```

it prints 2 3 4 1. Is this expected behavior? And if it is, what is the reason behind this?

Comment: With quaternions, w,x,y,z is no more or less correct than x,y,z,w.  Or put another way, if you choose to print `quat.w` first, it is no longer "mixed".

Comment: Yes, so In my program, I just follow the order w,x,y,z instead or regular x,y,z,w (at least regular when I was working with vec4) and everything works out fine. I am just curious as to why this is done in such manner.

Comment: Ah.  You are perhaps asking why `quat` and `vec4` chose _different_ orderings for variables that share the _same_ name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is really frustrating. Various maths libs use different conventions, but GLM seems to be inconsistent even internally (at least as of early 2018).

The constructor `glm::quat(...)` is **w, x, y, z**:

> quaternion.hpp:
> `GLM_FUNC_DECL GLM_CONSTEXPR tquat(T w, T x, T y, T z);`

<sub>* beware empty constructors no longer initialize to the identity. See [`GLM_FORCE_CTOR_INIT`](https://github.com/g-truc/glm/issues/735). Could add to CFLAGS.</sub>

The internal order is **x, y, z, w**:

> quaternion.hpp:
> `struct { T x, y, z, w;};`

Using `glm::make_quat` simply does a memcpy, which is **x, y, z, w**:

> type_ptr.inl:
> `memcpy(value_ptr(Result), ptr, sizeof(tquat<T, defaultp>));`

Using `glm::string_cast` gives **w, x, y, z**:

> string_cast.inl:
>
> ```
> return detail::format(FormatStr.c_str(),
>           static_cast<typename cast<T>::value_type>(x[3]),
>           static_cast<typename cast<T>::value_type>(x[0]),
>           static_cast<typename cast<T>::value_type>(x[1]),
>           static_cast<typename cast<T>::value_type>(x[2]));
> ```
>
> Note: The [] operator is `return (&x)[i];` (which assumes x is first)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my frustration with quats better than I did :). This was exactly my problem. As a beginner in the field of 3D graphics, I suffered for about 6 hours because of those inconsistencies. I was trying to debug my program and was getting unexpected results because I had no clue that the constructor and the internal order place  "W" component in different slots.

Comment: jozxyqk, just interested... did GLM stated somewhere that "empty constructors no longer initialize to the identity"? (This is a really important change that can cause big problems after migrating to the new GLM...)

Comment: @Gediminas yes. I had a small note about that and just expanded it to reference GLM_FORCE_CTOR_INIT.